# Add data in MySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, centos7

I want to add the data in MySQL database using python 2.7 on CentOS.

Here's my code,

```
# Sample data
clusterList =['a', 'w', 'e', 'r']
versionList = [1,2,3,4]
portalDomain = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
portalDomains = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4']

db = mysql.connect(host="mydb.com", user="nod", passwd="", db="noc")
cur = db.cursor()

for i in range(len(portalDomains)):
print("Adding data...")
query = "INSERT INTO test_score (portalCluster,portalVersion,portalDomain) values 
    ('%s', %s, '%s')" 
    % (clusterList[i], versionList[i], portalDomains[i])

cur.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

I am getting the error below,

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'release-20180822-16, 'portal.xyv.com')' at line 1")
```

I am able to the data manually in db using,

```
 cur.execute ("INSERT INTO test_release_score 
(portalCluster,portalVersion,portalDomain) values ('%s', %s, '%s')" 
% ("1122q", 7, "2wq2w"))
```

But, when I change it to something like below

```
# change 7 to 'qa22'

cur.execute ("INSERT INTO test_release_score 
(portalCluster,portalVersion,portalDomain) values ('%s', %s, '%s')" % 
("1122q", "qa12", "2wq2w"))
```

I get the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'qa12' in 'field list'")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you display the query in your question? After the values are substituted.

Comment: @MohitMotwani, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: query is a string right? But then you substitute '%s' with some values. Can you show the query after the substitution?Just give the output of the `print(query)`. Because your error displays a syntax error. Plus is possible also show schema of your database table for more clarity.

Comment: Here it is,    ('QUERY ==>', "INSERT INTO test_release_score 
      (portalCluster,portalVersion,portalDomain) values ('ClA', Ve22-16, 'pcom')")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of interpolating the values into the query with the `%` operator, use placeholders and query parameters:

```
query = ("INSERT INTO test_score (portalCluster,portalVersion,portalDomain) "
         "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)") 
cur.execute(query, (clusterList[i], versionList[i], portalDomains[i]))
```

This way the database driver will do the necessary escaping/quoting for you, which also prevents SQL-injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank a lot Eugene, it worked. Can you please tell what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: In your original query the second value is not quoted:  `('%s', %s, '%s')`; therefore it will be treated as a *column name* when it's a string.